# Using a regex counter as output

Tags: regex, counter, bbedit

Is there a counter that regex 'uses' that can be out put?

For instance, if I have this text:

```
(),
(),
(),
()
```

I want to use a regex pattern to add the count to the output for each match. so in this case the desired result would be:

```
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)
```

Surely there is an internal counter, but can it be used as output?

Comment: @roberthuttinger Does the programming language matter? Or does it have to use grep?

Comment: well from an educational standpoint, no. However if this does exist in GREP for bbedit, I would love to have it in my arsenal! I know that one can use preg_match and the $matches array, etc. with PHP